# Getting Original Column names after Aggregation in Spark with scala Code

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to know if there is an easy way to remove aggregate functions from dataframe columns after making an aggregation.
For example: I have a dataframe on which I have calculated the average of columns with Int or double Types. However after aggregation is done the columns are written like this `avg(column_name)`. I would like to remove avg and brackets from the column names.

Do you have any idea how to do it with a simple regex in spark2?

Here is how I do it today:

```
val aggregate =df.groupBy("column_name").agg(aggExprs.head,aggExprs.tail:_*).toDF()

val rename_column = aggregate.columns.foldLeft(aggregate){(newdf, colname) => newdf.withColumnRenamed(colname,colname.replace(",", "").replace(" ", "").replace("last", "").replace(")", "").replace("avg(",""))}
```

Any help would be welcome

Comment: use `alias` in your list of expressions `aggExprs`

Comment: Thank you for your answer blackbishop, but I have have more than 100 columns, is'n there a way to do it using a regular expression ?

Comment: Why don't you use the aliases while constructing the list of expressions? e.g. `val aggExprs = df.columns.map(c => avg(c).alias(c))`

Comment: Thank you so much @blackbishop. Thias solved my problem.